# I uninstalled Intel Optane Memory - The message says my computer won't boot after restart (Have restore point - will that work?)

Tags: linux, windows-10, raid, restore, optane

I uninstalled Intel Optane Memory, believing that would interfere with making a dual-boot system with Linux on a Lenovo Ideapad i7 (based on a guide).  There was a warning message about potential data loss, and a check box to read about it. I checked the box, and selected next.  The text file says my system will be unbootable after a re-start.  The application uninstall proceeded at the same time it opened the text file. (!!!)

I had made a restore point just before initiating that uninstall.  The uninstall window is still waiting for me to initiate the restart.  I have made two backups of all my data (not the OS stuff).  I really don't want to have to reinstall Windows, and Office, and all the licenses, etc., etc.  The computer didn't come with a CD/USB with the OS.  I realize I can download Windows - I'd have to research how to do that.  This is a one-year-old computer that came with Windows 10 (not Office).  (I do have Ubuntu on an external SSD, and it has grub on the SSD, not my internal hard drive, so that should still boot fine.  I actually made that install with the internal drive physically disconnected.)

Can I undo this?  Can I restore to that restore point right now?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**  It looks like if I can get into BIOS before the restart happens, I can select "deconcatinate" to dislable Optane - unless the key driver elements are already gone.  https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht504146

Does anyone know of a "deconcatinate" tool that will schedule itself to run?

The warning text document - They need to show this FIRST! (That's unbelievable - they warned about data loss before that, but not about an unbootable system):

```
WARNING!!!!!!!!!!!!WARNING!!!!!!!!!!WARNING!!!!!!!WARNING!!!!

WARNING: Removing the driver files may result in the loss of 
data on any RAID volumes currently used by the system. Removing 
the Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver from the boot drive or 
bootable RAID volume will remove access to the drive and will 
require reinstallation of the operating system. To preserve data
integrity, backup all data before proceeding.

Proceed ONLY if you absolutely have all your required data
backed up from all single drives and RAID volumes present in the
system and ONLY if you have no need to access these drives or 
volumes after this operation is completed!!! If this is not the
case, please cancel and exit this Uninstall application.

************************************************************
* DISCLAIMER
************************************************************

INFORMATION IN THIS DOCUMENT IS PROVIDED IN CONNECTION WITH INTEL PRODUCTS.
NO LICENSE, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, BY ESTOPPEL OR OTHERWISE, TO ANY
INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY RIGHTS IS GRANTED BY THIS DOCUMENT. EXCEPT AS
PROVIDED IN INTEL'S TERMS AND CONDITIONS OF SALE FOR SUCH PRODUCTS, INTEL
ASSUMES NO LIABILITY WHATSOEVER AND INTEL DISCLAIMS ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
WARRANTY, RELATING TO SALE AND/OR USE OF INTEL PRODUCTS INCLUDING LIABILITY
OR WARRANTIES RELATING TO FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
MERCHANTABILITY, OR INFRINGEMENT OF ANY PATENT, COPYRIGHT OR OTHER
INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY RIGHT.

UNLESS OTHERWISE AGREED IN WRITING BY INTEL, THE INTEL PRODUCTS ARE NOT 
DESIGNED NOR INTENDED FOR ANY APPLICATION IN WHICH THE FAILURE OF THE INTEL
PRODUCT COULD CREATE A SITUATION WHERE PERSONAL INJURY OR DEATH MAY OCCUR.

Intel may make changes to specifications and product descriptions at any
time, without notice. Designers must not rely on the absence or 
characteristics of any features or instructions marked "reserved"
or "undefined". Intel reserves these for future definition and shall have
no responsibility whatsoever for conflicts or incompatibilities arising
from future changes to them. The information here is subject to change
without notice. Do not finalize a design with this information.

The products described in this document may contain design defects or
errors known as errata which may cause the product to deviate from 
published specifications. Current characterized errata are available on 
request.

Contact your local Intel sales office or your distributor to obtain the 
latest specifications and before placing your product order.

Copies of documents which have an order number and are referenced in this
document, or other Intel literature, may be obtained by calling 
1-800-548-4725, or go to: http://www.intel.com/#/en_us_01 

Intel(R) is a trademark of Intel Corporation in the U.S. and other countries.

* Other names and brands may be claimed as the property of others


Copyright (C), Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using the Restore Point.

The advise I received here was way off.  People need to take note.  (Update - Most of the comments I was referring to have been deleted.)

I got a warning in the BIOS when I tried to change to AHCI, - if you continue all data on your hard drive will be deleted - so I said NO.  I hard powered down to avoid a restart, and what would have been the blue screen of death.  I put it a Windows 10 upgrade/install USB, and tried to do an upgrade to 1909.  It told me I couldn't couldn't do a boot-up upgrade on the same computer, and I had to to the upgrade from within Windows (which meant rebooting - and failure).  I hard-powered down again and rebooted with the Windows USB, and selected repair.  Then I selected the Restore Point.  It said it would reinstall the Optane drivers, but they might have a problem and should be reinstalled.  The restore proceeded okay, and my system booted up okay.

I found a couple of posts about this model of laptop, and a few others, where AHCI can't be disabled, without a complete reinstall of the OS.  There's a reason this computer isn't listed on Ubuntu's compatible computers list.  I'm going to leave Ubuntu on the external SSD. (Update. Linux is working on the external SSD.  Optane is enabled with the internal drive / Windows).

Here are three screencaps from the BIOS showing that the disk will be erased if I change to ACHI.  (ACHI is the alternative to RST/Optane.)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @JimK39 - That message only applies to the devices that have been added to the Intel RAID (Intel RST) or the Optane drive itself.  Of course you can't use the Optane drive without Intel RST enabled (in the firmware) and the drivers installed (within Windows).

Comment: My drive is listed under the RAID section the window before the configuration screen.  RST stands for Rapid Storage Technology, which is running in my system, as is Optane.

Answer (score 1):

Check your BIOS settings. There must be something called "Storage Controller" or with similar name with two options "AHCI" and "intel rapid storage technology".

Switch to AHCI and save settings and restart. It might solve your issue.

Comment: Switching to AHCI was the plan.  Checking BIOS requires restart - and if that message is right, my system will be dead.  I know how to boot into BIOS from Windows 10 ...

Comment: @JimK39 "Memory was being attached to the hard drives with RAID" What?

Comment: @Ramhound - If I had switched to ACHI my hard drive would have been erased.  See the BIOS warning message I posted in my answer.  Had I not used the Restore Point method, I would have been reinstalling Windows.

Comment: @JimK39 - I actually suggested you could reinstall the drivers before you performed a restart, although I indicated Intel RST, but I only did that because those are Intel’s RAID drivers used by Intel Optane.  Unfortunately, while you indicate you were using a Intel Optane device, you did not indicate, you were actually using Intel RST (in your question).  My suggestion was based on incomplete information.  Although I suspect of your not using Intel RST, for a RAID, the warring was limited to the Optane device not your system drive.

Comment: @Ramhound - You suggested changing to ACHI from within Windows, and I replied that I only see how to do that in BIOS. You also suggested rebooting and changing to ACHI.  You never said anything about reinstalling the Optane drivers before rebooting.  I was trying to find a way to do that, though.  There was that pending dialog that my computer had to be restarted to complete the uninstallation.  I reinstalled the drivers by using the Restore Point, rather than rebooting and allowing the uninstall to complete.  And you deleted your comments.  My above references are now to nothing.

Comment: @JimK39 - I deleted my previous comment because it was based on incomplete information.  So the information was incorrect.

Comment: Okay.  On my system, there are only two options, ACHI, and RST with Optane.  You can see that in the BIOS screencaps in my answer.  Thanks for your help.